# this context lost when passing a reference to a method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

In this example

```
class Car {
    describe() {
        console.log("I have " + this.wheels);
    }

    testMe() {
        setTimeout( this.describe, 1000);
    }

    constructor(wheels) {
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }
}

let myCar = new Car(4);
myCar.testMe(); // I have undefined
```

How come the expected value of `this` isn't passed inside the `describe` function ?

edit : Can you confirm that is setTimeout was an arrow function, I wouldn't get `undefined` ?

Comment: Btw, I wrote an answer about a similar question  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42103809/3889043).

Comment: Why have you added the `typescript` tag?

Answer (score 0):

A bare function reference has no context, even if it was retrieved as a property of an object.

Within your `testMe` function you need either:

```
setTimeout(() => this.describe(), 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(this.describe.bind(this), 1000);
```

or

```
let self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.describe();
}, 1000);
```

That last one could be written as an arrow function, of course, but if you're doing that you might as well use the first version, with no local copy of `this` required.

Regarding your edit, it *is* possible to pass just `this.describe` by making `describe` an arrow function, assigned from inside the constructor, but note that this then means that every instance of the object would have its own copy of that function instead of there just being a single copy on the `prototype` of the class:

```
constructor(wheels) {
    this.wheels = wheels;

    this.describe = () => {
        console.log("I have " + this.wheels);
    }
}
```

Comment: because without bind or call or apply it is equivalent to writing            setTimeout( function() {
                console.log("I have " + this.wheels);
            }, 1000);

Comment: @Lev what's your point?   The code you've written in that comment wouldn't work either.